# API: How to loop through a dynamic range while moving the "stop"?

Tags: python, pandas, api, range

I am working on extracting a report using the API. The API has a max offset of 1000 at a time, so I have set the for loop as `range(start=0, stop=10000, step=1000)`. Sometimes, my report will have more than 10,000 rows, in that case I want the `stop` variable of the range to be updated to `11000`.

How can I keep the `end` dynamic, rather than keeping a fixed number? Also, I am using the `sleep` option since my API has a limit of 120 calls per minute. Is there any better way than just adding sleep?

```
def get_data(auth_headers):
    
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    for offset in range(0, 10000, 1000):
        
        project_params = {"limit": 1000, "offset": offset}
        res = requests.get(f"https://api.website.io/core/reports/{report_id}"
                            ,params=project_params
                            ,headers=auth_headers)
        data = json_normalize(res.json())

        if res.status_code == 200 and res.json() != []:
            df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
            time.sleep(0.2)
        elif res.json() == []:
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(2)
            continue

    return df
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you don't know the number of lines in the report ahead of time, you should replace your for loop with a while loop and break out of it when after receiving less than 1000 lines:

```
offset = 0
while True:
   ...
   make the request, process the data, etc.
   ...
   if "less than 1000 lines returned": break
   ...
   offset += 1000
```

If you do know the number of lines beforehand, you can let the range function do that for you:

```
for offset in range(0,numberOfLines,1000):
    ...
    limit = min(1000,numberOfLines-offset)
    ...
```

Comment: I do not know the count of lines. Also, I created the if condition as `if len(data) == 1000: offset+=1000 elif len(data) < 1000: break elif len(data) == 0: break`. Is there a cleaner way of doing this, as I had to put the `df.append` statement in the first two conditions.

Comment: `offset+=1000` is only needed at the very end of the loop.  You should break before reaching that and you only need to check `if len(data) < 1000: break` because that also covers the case of `len(data)==0`.  In fact, the condition you already have (`res.json() == []:break` ) may be enough for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the row count from your DataFrame() object by getting the length (len()) of the DataFrame object's index. Then you can round up to the nearest 1000 using this method:

```
row_count = len(df.index)
stop = math.ceil(row_count/1000)*1000
for offset in range(0, stop, 1000):
etc.
```

This will require the importing of the Math module `import math`. Let me know if you would like a more in depth explanation on the rounding function.

Comment: Since I am defining an empty DataFrame out of the for loop, the stop will have the value 0, and the loop with stop there itself.

Comment: You're right Shantanu, I didn't realize that and apologize. Then Alain's answer of a while loop is the better option!